# Como resuelvo BadMethodCallException, Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::filter()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, filtro

Estoy tratando de filtrar los resultados desde la consulta en Eloquent, pero me marca el error `BadMethodCallException`. Según yo lo estoy haciendo todo bien.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```php
public function index(SearchRequest $searchRequest, ConfigurationFilter $filters)
    {
        $filtered_configurations = Configuration::whereTrash(false)->with(['customs.properties', 'properties'])->filter($filters);

        $types = $this->getConfigurationTypes();
        $authors = $this->getAuthors();

        return view('configuration.assistant.index', [
            'configurations' => $filtered_configurations->paginate(10),
            'authors' => $authors,
            'types' => $types,
        ]);
    }
```

Donde `SearchRequest` es:

```php
class SearchRequest extends FormRequest {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::user()->author != null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Donde `ConfigurationFilter` es:

```php
class ConfigurationFilter extends ModelFilter
{
    public function name($value)
    {
        return $this->builder->where('name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
    }

    public function author($id)
    {
        return $this->builder->whereIn('user_id', explode(',', $id));
    }

    public function type($type)
    {
        return $this->builder->whereIn('category_id', explode(',', $type));
    }

    public function status($status)
    {
        return $this->builder->whereEnabled($status == 'enabled');
    }
}
```

Donde `ModelFilter` es:

```php
class ModelFilter extends QueryFilter implements Filter
{
    public function id($id)
    {
        return $this->builder->whereIn('id', explode(',', $id));
    }

    public function from($date)
    {
        return $this->builder->where('created_at', '>=', $date);
    }

    public function to($date)
    {
        return $this->builder->where('created_at', '<=', $date);
    }

    public function enabled($status)
    {
        return $this->builder->whereEnabled($status === 'true');
    }

    public function trash($status)
    {
        return $this->builder->whereTrash($status === 'true');
    }

    public function take($limit = 100)
    {
        return $this->builder->take($limit);
    }
}
```

Donde `ModelFilter` es:

```php
interface Filter {

    public function id($id);

    public function from($date);

    public function to($date);

    public function enabled($status);

    public function trash($status);

    public function take($limit = 100);
}
```

¿Que me estará faltando?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué intentas hacer con el método filter?

Comment: Intento filtrar, en base a `ConfigurationFilter`

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver agregando la siguiente función al modelo: ```public function scopeFilter($query, QueryFilter $filters)
    {
        return $filters->apply($query);
    }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude resolver agregando la siguiente función al modelo:

```php
public function scopeFilter($query, QueryFilter $filters)
{
    return $filters->apply($query);
}
```